# Unknown error in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, counter, error

I am currently getting an error saying that my "counter_2" is not a constant. I am also getting a syntax error when I use "<=" with my counter_2.

I've attached screenshots of my error and my code below.

Thanks for the help!

```
module counter_2( out, wave );
input out;
output wave ;

//wrapper
counter_2 wrapper (
.out(out)
);
reg [7:0] counter_2;
//<statements>

if (counter_2 < out + 1'b1)
    begin
    counter_2 <= counter_2 + 1;
    wave <= 1'b1;
    end
else if (counter_2 == out + 1'b1)
    begin
    counter_2 <= 8'b0;
    wave <= 1'b0;
    end
end
endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: You are comparing the 8 bit 'counter_2' to a 1 bit 'out' - that's not going to do what you want. Also, probably best to avoid 'out' as a variable name. You can see by the color syntaxing of your editor that 'out' is being treated as a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many errors here, it's probably not worth trying to figure out exactly which one is making the synthesizer barf.

- You're trying to instantiate a `counter_2` module within the `counter_2` module. Verilog doesn't support turtles-all-the-way-down technology, so this is not going to work.
- You're using the name `counter_2` to refer to both your module and a register signal in your module. That is likely to cause problems.
- You haven't used `always @(some condition)` or `initial` to say when you want the assignments to `counter_2` and `wave` to happen. You need to use either `always` or `initial` to introduce a procedural block. You can't just make procedural statements in the top level of your module.